CFImage problems after updated to the last version of Coldfusion
<!--- Parse the users --->  
<cfoutput query="CreatedBThumbnail">
<cfif #IsBinary(CreatedBThumbnail.GroupImageContent)#>
<cfimage source="#CreatedBThumbnail.GroupImageContent#" action="resize" isBase64="yes" width="200" height="200" destination="#ThePath##CreatedBThumbnail.ID#.png" overwrite="yes">
<cfelse>
<!--- Copy the default Image--->
<cffile action = "copy" source="#application.basePath#\Assets\images\groups_32.png" destination="#ThePath##CreatedBThumbnail.ID#.png">
</cfif>
</cfoutput> 

the binary content is creating an error with the cfimage : An exception occurred while trying to read the image.Error reading PNG image data The specific sequence of files
that line got the error :
<cfimage source="#CreatedBThumbnail.GroupImageContent#" action="resize" isBase64="yes" width="200" height="200" destination="#ThePath##CreatedBThumbnail.ID#.png" overwrite="yes"\>

even if i try to go back of version, now the problem sticks

Coldfusion version is 2021 Enterprise

Thanks rrk for aranging my code, not used to post here...Thanks... Mike

I think there is a misconception. You are checking with isBinary() if the value is binary. So you are using pure binary data as source. On the other hand you are setting the isBase64 attribute to true, which would typically expect a string representation of binary. I'm pretty sure you also need to use  a base64 string data image representation of that binary in the source attribute then and NOT a pure binary data.

Many thanks AndreasRU for your advice, so what should be the code ? to achieve what I am trying to do

Try embracing the binary content with toBase64() in the cfimage source attribute like this: toBase64(CreatedBThumbnail.GroupImageContent) and retry.

Many thanks AndreasRu, it works .... Great !!!

@AndreasRu please consider posting this as an answer, so the OP can accept

Because I've already given a solution within my comments, I'm posting it as an answer for posterity and completeness:
The error you've posted is clearly saying that the cfimage tag isn't  capable of reading the value of its source attribute that is delivered through the variable CreatedBThumbnail.GroupImageContent. This value must be a binary because the condition isBinay(CreatedBThumbnail.GroupImageContent) of your code is returning the boolean true.
On the other hand you are setting isBase64="yes" within your cfimage tag. A base64 is not a binary value, but a string representation of a binary value using the base64() encoding. Thus a solution would be to encode your binary with base64(), e.g.:
<!--- Parse the users ---> 
<cfoutput query="CreatedBThumbnail"> 
  <cfif IsBinary(CreatedBThumbnail.GroupImageContent)>
    <cfimage source="#toBase64(CreatedBThumbnail.GroupImageContent)#" action="resize" isBase64="yes" width="200" height="200" destination="#ThePath##CreatedBThumbnail.ID#.png" overwrite="yes">
  <cfelse>
    <!--- Copy the default Image---> 
    <cffile action = "copy" source="#application.basePath#\Assets\images\groups_32.png" destination="#ThePath##CreatedBThumbnail.ID#.png">
  </cfif> 
</cfoutput>


